# "Unsatisfied Dependencies" - Different Stateless Beans with same Interface

Tags: cdi, java-ee-7

I have three `@Stateless` Beans with the same interface.

```
public interface ReportService
{
    List<String> determineRelevantData();

    Report generate(ReportRequest request, Locale locale) throws ServiceFailedException;
}
```

I inject the beans in one facade bean:

```
@Stateless
public class ReportServiceFacadeBean implements ReportServiceFacadeLocal
{
    @Inject
    private FirstReportBean firstReport;

    @Inject
    private SecondReportBean secondReport;

    @Inject
    private ThirdReportBean thirdReport;

    [...]
}
```

When I deploy it this way, I get:

> WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type
>   SecondReportBean with qualifiers @Default at 
>   injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private
>   ReportServiceFacadeBean.secondReport

When I uncomment the interface in the implementing beans the server starts up without any error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Unless I miss my guess, the error message is incomplete. Are there any additional lines following, esp. talking about ambiguos dependencies or the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EJB beans have a bit different bean types, which are then used for injection, compared to CDI beans. Namely you will want to inject EJB beans by their client-visible parts, meaning interfaces (unless you have no-interface view).

This is fully backed by spec, here is [one chapter from CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#bean_types_ee) that mentions it (with links to other).

In your case you will have to introduce [qualifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#qualifiers) and then inject the beans like:

```
@Inject
@SomeQualifier
ReportService firstService;
```