# Unsatisfied dependency for container managed Stateless bean after adding interface implementation

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I had some processor classes which did not implement any interface:

```
public class Processor1 {
}

@Stateles
public class Processor2 {
}

public class Processor3 {
}
```

One of them is a container managed Stateless bean.

Service class has all the processors injected:

```
public class MyService {
    @Inject private Processor1 p1;
    @Inject private Processor2 p2;
    @Inject private Processor3 p3;
}
```

Than I had a requirement that all processors should implement an interfase ProcessorInterfase;

After I changed the code, deployment failed with error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Processor2 with qualifiers @Default
```

Ok. I created a new Qualifier @Process2Bean and added it to Processor2 declaration:

```
@Stateles
@Process2Bean
public class Processor2 {
}
```

and to injection point:

```
public class MyService {
    @Inject private Processor1 p1;
    @Inject @Process2Bean private Processor2 p2;
    @Inject private Processor3 p3;
}
```

Now I have the following deployment error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Processor2 with qualifiers @Process2Bean
at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Process2Bean private a.b.c.MyService.p2
```

Did I do something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Strange, the imO the Qualifier should not be necessary. What happens if you annotate Processor p2 with @EJB instead of @Inject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a twist on a problem I answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607789/5342297).

In short, when you are injecting EJB beans, you need to inject them based on their client-visible parts - interfaces. Unless, of course, you have no-interface view as was your original scenario. [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#bean_types_ee) covers this if you want to have a read.

You are going to have to inject `Processor2` via `ProcessorInterfase`. But there are three implementations, so that would lead to ambiguous dependency, hence you will also need the qualifier. Final solution can then look like this:

```
@Inject
@Process2Bean
ProcessorInterfase processor2;
```

Comment: Sorry, was on vacation.